# Wordpress "remember me" - How should it work?

Tags: wp-login-form

In my installation WP 4.6.1, on login forms the checkbox "Remember me" may be used, however credentials will be empty on next login.

Users usually logout, I wonder if this is the problem, or should the browser (cookie) remember credentials?

In a few words: how the "remember me" option should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checkbox is under the supervision of the browser cookies. Users can disable the `Save password` function globally or on the per-site basis. Also, sometimes browsers ignore this checkbox due to some reasons, especially with some cookie-related add-ons installed. For example, my clean installation of the latest Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 started to decline to save passwords one day, whereas it still offers me to save them.

Comment: Thank you Max. So the fact that the credentials are lost is not due to the user logging out. How can I ensure the credentials are saved? I am facing some 200 users grumbling because credentials are lost and they need to enter them each time

Comment: I am now making some test. If users login and close the tab of the browser without logging out, next time they connect, the username is present but the password no. So one step is to do not logout otherwise credentials are wiped out. But the password is not there. Why?

Comment: I have disabled all plugins and reverted to basic theme, and now when closing the tab and opening a new session, user will be granted to access dashboard without any further login. There must be a plugin or theme that will alter this. What code should I look for that may alter login behaviour?

Comment: You never mentioned 200 users are facing the problem. So, it seems not to be the browser or cookie problem. So, please, refuse my answer. Try to disable plugins one by one to figure out the conflicting one.

Comment: Max you're fine! I think I have traced a pattern. Basically, if you logout, WP will forget credentials. I think the problem was due to this! Since I have stopped logging out, on a new browser session, access is granted automatically!